# Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression for Map

Tags: java, templates, lambda

I have the following class (template that I was using) This is just the minimal reproducible example.

```
public final class MyTemplate {
    public static <T> T execute(
            Supplier<T> oldCode,
            Supplier<T> newCode) {

        return executeInternal(
                oldCode,
                newCode
        );
    }
 ........
}
```

And I use the above template in another class like:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
    public Map<Long, String> getRepresentation(Collection<Apple> apples) {
        return MyTemplate.execute(
                            // super returns the same type
                () -> SomeInterface.super.getRepresentation(apples), // error
                () -> myNewMethod(apples)                            // error
        );
    }

    private Map<Long, String> myNewMethod(Collection<Apple> apples) {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

The above 2 `error` lines throw the compilation error:

> Required type: Map <java.lang.Long,java.lang.String> Provided: T
>
> Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

I've been using the template's `execute` method previously, but now it's throwing this error. What could be the problem? Why isn't `Map` identified as a `T`?

Comment: Does `SomeInterface.super.getRepresentation(...)` return a `Map<Long, String>`?

Comment: @Slaw Yes it returns the same type

Comment: I tried to reproduce the compiler error with your code (filling in some blanks) but was unable to. It compiles just fine for me (Java 18.0.1).